# Как проверить диапазон управляющих символов (\) Java

Tags: java

Подскажите как задать диапазон управляющих символов ( backspace , space....) . То есть мне нужно проверить является ли нажатая клавиша управляющей .
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: А как вы получаете информацию о нажатой клавише?

Answer (score 2):

С каких это пор `space` является управляющим символом? Вы как то определитесь что такое для вас управляющий символ. На всякий случай посмотрите в сторону `KeyEvent.isActionKey()` - может это то?